# How can I use a regular expression to match or replace passwords containing only numeric values

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regexp-replace

I am attempting to find a regex pattern that allows me to match a simple, yet specific pattern.
The password requirements are that the string is not made up only numeric characters. It can contain any amount of alphanumeric, special characters, etc.

This is the original output

```
[{"line":"test@test.com:12345"},{"line":"test@test.com:abcxyz"},{"line":"test@test.com:abc123"},{"line":"test@test.com:73chesterfield"}]
```

What I am trying to achieve

```
test@test.com:abcxyz
test@test.com:abc123
```

My knowledge of regex is very limited, but I have tried searching for a solution the better part of this week with no success.

The closest thing  I have been able to do is clean the output so it is just
`12345`,`abcxyz`,`abc123` and then using an expression like `"^[a-zA-Z]*$"` and somehow taking the strings matching my criteria, and connecting those back to the email.

The biggest issue I am having is that I know it is possible, but I am unsure what the exact methods involved are, and what area of regex I should be focusing on. Any suggestions to a solution, or even pointing me in the direction on where to continue my research would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what it is that you're after... However, here are some examples:

```
/(\w+@[\w\.]+:\w+)/    // Will match passwords made up of "word characters" [a-Z0-9_]

/(\w+@[\w\.]+:.*?)(?<!\\)"/    // This will match passwords with any character (even escaped ")
```

Comment: I apologize if I did a poor job at explaining, but the first example you provided was exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you very much !